# MongoDB Creating Backups and Point In Time Restores

Tags: mongodb, database-backups

I'm a SQL Server DBA trying to use MongoDB for some particular cases. What I have at the moment is 3 node replica set with 2 data bearing nodes and 1 arbiter. The thing that i'm struggling at the moment is finding a clear answer on ho to create Backups that will allow me a point in time restores, similar to what you have in MS SQL with FULL and LOG backups. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongodb provides different methods to Backup and restore

**1. Back Up with Atlas(cloud based AWS services)**

**2. Back Up with MongoDB Cloud Manager or Ops Manager**(Enterprise edition only. Supports backing up and restoring MongoDB replica sets and sharded clusters from a graphical user interface.)

**3. Back Up with file system snapshot on OS**( on Linux, the Logical Volume Manager (LVM) can create snapshots. Similarly, Amazon’s EBS storage system for EC2 supports snapshots)
To get a correct snapshot of a running mongod process, you must have journaling enabled. Without journaling enabled, there is no guarantee that the snapshot  will be consistent or valid.

**To create a snapshot with LVM, issue a command as root in the following format:**

lvcreate --size 100M --snapshot --name mdb-snap01 /dev/vg0/mongodb
This command creates an LVM snapshot (with the --snapshot option) named mdb-snap01 of the mongodb volume in the vg0 volume group.

This example creates a snapshot named mdb-snap01 located at /dev/vg0/mdb-snap01. The location and paths to your systems volume groups and devices may vary slightly depending on your operating system’s LVM configuration.

**To restore a snapshot , issue the following sequence of commands:**

umount /dev/vg0/mdb-snap01

lvcreate --size 1G --name mdb-new vg0

dd if=/dev/vg0/mdb-snap01 of=/dev/vg0/mdb-new

mount /dev/vg0/mdb-new /srv/mongodb

for more details https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/#back-up-and-restore-using-lvm-on-linux

**4.Back Up with mongodump (Terminal based Mongodb tools)**

mongodump and mongorestore are simple and efficient tools for backing up and restoring small MongoDB deployments

mongodump and mongorestore operate against a running mongod process

If you dont specify any database it captures all the databases and copies into seperate folder along with indexes(json format) for every database

By default, mongodump does not backup the local database(which contains Replicaset configuration & oplog.rs collection).

For replica sets, mongodump provides the --oplog option to include in its output oplog entries that occur during the mongodump operation. This allows the corresponding mongorestore operation to replay the captured oplog. To restore a backup created with --oplog, use mongorestore with the --oplogReplay option.

Mongorestore captures only database files. indexes must be rebuild after restoring the data.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/#

**commands:**

mongodump --out /data/backup/  (It backups all the databases and indexes)

mongodump --collection myCollection --db test  (specified database & collection)
mongorestore --port